# How can I prevent width:100vw from causing a scrollbar to appear?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, border-box

I partially got the idea after ready [Chris Coyier's article on hacking up CSS Triangles](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/) from object borders.

**IMPORTANT:** Let me first state that I **understand** that in most cases, you would use `width:100%`, however, I am working with **borders** and you can't use percentages with borders

I also am really really really trying to **avoid** using JavaScript for this solution. Please refrain from answering with JavaScript solutions as I already know how to do this with JavaScript. I also do not like the idea of setting the body max-width to 100%. I do not want to limit any overflow constraints for this project.

```css
[class*='section-'] {
    min-height: 100vh;
    padding: 20px;
}

.section-blue {background-color: blue;}
.section-red {background-color: red;}
.section-green {background-color: green;}

[class*='divider-'] {
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 25vh solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 0vh solid transparent;
    border-left: 0vw solid transparent;
    border-right: 100vw solid transparent;
}
.divider-blue-red {
    border-top-color: blue;
    border-right-color: red;
}
.divider-red-green {
    border-top-color: red;
    border-right-color: green;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-blue">[Text Goes Here]</section>
<div class="divider-blue-red"></div>
<section class="section-red">[Text Goes Here]</section>
<div class="divider-red-green"></div>
<section class="section-green">[Text Goes Here]</section>
```

[Click Here To View Live Demo](http://srkdev.azurewebsites.net/stackoverflow-question.html)

**GOALS**

1. Have `.divider-blue-red` && `.divider-red-green` elements extent to 100% of the view window NOT including the scrollbar
2. Not use JavaScript (pure CSS solution)
3. Not setting body to 'max-width:100%`
4. Have a cool fluid design that rolls with the device width and height!

Comment: have you tried calc property of CSS and then you may subtract some portion from the 100vh and you may be able to remove the scroll effect

Comment: Yes, I have done something like 'border-width:calc(100vw - 17px)` however that only works for chrome on desktop. When I then view it in a browser that has scroll bars with a different dimension or on a mobile browser things are shifted to the left :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One posible solution is to change the way you create the triangles. Instead of the border trick, use a gradient image

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  font-size: 18px;
}
[class*='section-'] {
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 20px;
}
.section-blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.section-red {
  background-color: red;
}
.section-green {
  background-color: green;
}
[class*='divider-'] {
  display: block;
  height: 25vh;
  width: 100%;
}
.divider-blue-red {
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, blue 50%, red 50%);
}
.divider-red-green {
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, red 50%, green 50%);
}
```

```html
<section class="section-blue">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vulputate, nibh vitae dignissim euismod, ex elit consequat est, vitae placerat magna nunc sed lectus. Suspendisse vehicula elementum nulla id dictum. Nulla a efficitur erat. Proin consequat
  justo sit amet ultricies vehicula. Proin facilisis metus a velit volutpat, sit amet rutrum quam commodo. Ut quam justo, congue vel elit commodo, molestie scelerisque nisi. Etiam auctor lacinia pretium. Nulla vel dui et diam dictum dignissim non vitae
  metus. Vivamus arcu arcu, finibus vitae ante nec, porta aliquam nunc. Vivamus pellentesque est in posuere mollis. Aenean non lectus id nunc ultrices gravida.
</section>
<div class="divider-blue-red"></div>
<section class="section-red">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vulputate, nibh vitae dignissim euismod, ex elit consequat est, vitae placerat magna nunc sed lectus. Suspendisse vehicula elementum nulla id dictum. Nulla a efficitur erat. Proin consequat
  justo sit amet ultricies vehicula. Proin facilisis metus a velit volutpat, sit amet rutrum quam commodo. Ut quam justo, congue vel elit commodo, molestie scelerisque nisi. Etiam auctor lacinia pretium. Nulla vel dui et diam dictum dignissim non vitae
  metus. Vivamus arcu arcu, finibus vitae ante nec, porta aliquam nunc. Vivamus pellentesque est in posuere mollis. Aenean non lectus id nunc ultrices gravida.
</section>
<div class="divider-red-green"></div>
<section class="section-green">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vulputate, nibh vitae dignissim euismod, ex elit consequat est, vitae placerat magna nunc sed lectus. Suspendisse vehicula elementum nulla id dictum. Nulla a efficitur erat. Proin consequat
  justo sit amet ultricies vehicula. Proin facilisis metus a velit volutpat, sit amet rutrum quam commodo. Ut quam justo, congue vel elit commodo, molestie scelerisque nisi. Etiam auctor lacinia pretium. Nulla vel dui et diam dictum dignissim non vitae
  metus. Vivamus arcu arcu, finibus vitae ante nec, porta aliquam nunc. Vivamus pellentesque est in posuere mollis. Aenean non lectus id nunc ultrices gravida.
</section>
```

In this solution, usually the divider line between the 2 colors isn't as smooth as in your current solution

Another workaround could be using calc. Since there are variations in scrol bar width, set a value higher than expected, and use a shadow to fill the (posible) empty space.

In the browsers with smaller scrool bar, there will be a small amount of horizontal separation on the right. But I don't think this is much noticeable

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  font-size: 18px;
}
[class*='section-'] {
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 20px;
}
.section-blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.section-red {
  background-color: red;
}
.section-green {
  background-color: green;
}
  [class*='divider-']
  {
   display: block;
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border-top: 25vh solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 0vh solid transparent;
   border-left: 0vw solid transparent;
   border-right: calc(100vw - 20px) solid transparent;
  }

  .divider-blue-red
  {
   border-top-color: blue;
   border-right-color: red;
          box-shadow: 20px 0px red;
  }

  .divider-red-green
  {
   border-top-color: red;
   border-right-color: green;
          box-shadow: 20px 0px green;
  }
```

```html
<section class="section-blue">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vulputate, nibh vitae dignissim euismod, ex elit consequat est, vitae placerat magna nunc sed lectus. Suspendisse vehicula elementum nulla id dictum. Nulla a efficitur erat. Proin consequat
  justo sit amet ultricies vehicula. Proin facilisis metus a velit volutpat, sit amet rutrum quam commodo. Ut quam justo, congue vel elit commodo, molestie scelerisque nisi. Etiam auctor lacinia pretium. Nulla vel dui et diam dictum dignissim non vitae
  metus. Vivamus arcu arcu, finibus vitae ante nec, porta aliquam nunc. Vivamus pellentesque est in posuere mollis. Aenean non lectus id nunc ultrices gravida.
</section>
<div class="divider-blue-red"></div>
<section class="section-red">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vulputate, nibh vitae dignissim euismod, ex elit consequat est, vitae placerat magna nunc sed lectus. Suspendisse vehicula elementum nulla id dictum. Nulla a efficitur erat. Proin consequat
  justo sit amet ultricies vehicula. Proin facilisis metus a velit volutpat, sit amet rutrum quam commodo. Ut quam justo, congue vel elit commodo, molestie scelerisque nisi. Etiam auctor lacinia pretium. Nulla vel dui et diam dictum dignissim non vitae
  metus. Vivamus arcu arcu, finibus vitae ante nec, porta aliquam nunc. Vivamus pellentesque est in posuere mollis. Aenean non lectus id nunc ultrices gravida.
</section>
<div class="divider-red-green"></div>
<section class="section-green">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vulputate, nibh vitae dignissim euismod, ex elit consequat est, vitae placerat magna nunc sed lectus. Suspendisse vehicula elementum nulla id dictum. Nulla a efficitur erat. Proin consequat
  justo sit amet ultricies vehicula. Proin facilisis metus a velit volutpat, sit amet rutrum quam commodo. Ut quam justo, congue vel elit commodo, molestie scelerisque nisi. Etiam auctor lacinia pretium. Nulla vel dui et diam dictum dignissim non vitae
  metus. Vivamus arcu arcu, finibus vitae ante nec, porta aliquam nunc. Vivamus pellentesque est in posuere mollis. Aenean non lectus id nunc ultrices gravida.
</section>
```

Comment: I'll give this a shot tonight and see how I like it. Looks like a potentially viable solution..  I'm not the BIGGEST fan of gradients, but it might just be the way to get around this. I'll let you know how it goes tonight when I get some time to mess around with this!

Comment: This does seem to be a pretty viable solution! I don't really like the jagged edges very much, but maybe there is a way to get rid of those? If anyone else has a solution, please let me know! :)

Answer (score -1):

read this and it might help

When I give it a margin of -1 em, it gets wider. Can go in here and change the value again, zero, -1 em, zero, -1 em. The problem is, I need to find the exact value, because if I make this -2 em, all of the sudden, I get a scrollbar on the bottom, and I'm allowed to scroll left and right, because now the container is bigger than the viewport. That's simply not going to work. Now I'm sure you're thinking at this point, "Well, this is not that hard.

"All you have to do is go to the main that has the margin, "and here you see the margin is 1.4 ems, "and then just apply a 1.4 em to the entry meta." The problem is, that's not going to work. You see, if I go and say -1.4 ems here, it looks like it spans all the way, but if you look really closely, you can see there's a slight white line here on the left and the right side. That's because even though the margin is 1.4 em on the main, it is actually 1.4-something em in the entry meta, because we are using em sizes to size the content, and you notice the entry meta has a font size of 95%.

That means to get the em size, I have to figure out the difference between the inner container and the outer container. So let me take a sidebar and explain to you how em sizes can be calculated. We need two elements before we can do this. First I'll go to main and find out what the font size is. See right down here, font size 14.4 pixels. Remember that. Then we'll go to entry meta and do the same thing. What is the font size here? 13.68 So we have 14.4 and 13.68.

Now for the sidebar, how to calculate em values. We have two containers. The parent container has a font size of 1 em, and the calculated font size in the browser is 14.4 pixels. The nested container has a font size of 95%, and the calculated font size here is 13.68. 13.68 is 95% of 14.4. The parent container has a margin of 1.4 ems, and in the browser, that's equivalent to 25.902 pixels.

Now I need to figure out what em value I can set in the nested container to get that same 25.902 pixels. To do that, I'm going to use two formulas. First, I'll grab the parent font size and divide it by the nested font size. This gives me the relative difference between the two. When you do this math, you're likely to come up with a really weird number, like 1.052631 da da da da da da. Now we need to save this number and add it into a new formula, that takes the parent em size, so in our case, 1.4, and times it with the relative difference, that 1.05

This gives us the nested em size that we need to target. In our example, the result of all this math gives us 1.47368421052632, and that is the value we're going to use. In between the previous movie on this one, I made some slight changes to our CSS, so if you want to follow along at this point, you need to grab the exercise files for 06-05. In style.css, you'll see that here, under the entry meta rule, I've created two new properties.

First I have the margin value that sets top and bottom to zero and left and right to -1.47368 da da da. That's the number that we just got. Then I've done the same in the padding, giving the box a padding of the same value. That's done so that if the content within this box spans enough to the left or right, it won't accidentally touch the edges of the viewport. As you can see in the browser, by adding these two properties, our content is now spanning the full width of the viewport. However, if you start scaling up the viewport now, you'll notice that at some point, you'll hit a break point.

And I've already accounted for that break point here. We have a break point at 30 ems, and here I have to change that margin value, because at that break point, the margin around the content switches from 1.4 to 1.8. As a result, we now get -1.8947 etcetera. So that solves the smaller screens. But what of this big screen, where the content floats in the middle? Well here we have to do something completely different, and that's why I've commented out this section, so I can fully explain what's going on.

I'll take the comments away, and then we'll look at this media query. When the screen is wider than 57 ems, we are locking the width of the main content and floating it in the center. To get the entry meta to span the full width, we now have to figure out how wide is the actual viewport, and then position the entry meta according to that. And what I've done here is use a new unit of measurement that is in CSS3 called vw or viewport width. So I've set it up as follows. If the browser supports the vw unit, then the width of the entry meta will be as wide as the viewport.

Then I have to subtract the width of our content, so 52.2 ems from the viewport width, but I have to do this in a backwards way because of math. So here we have -100 viewport width plus 52.2. That gives us all the viewport width minus the main content. And then I divide that by two, and shift the content to the left by that value. The end result of this, you'll see when I reload the page. Now the content spans the full width, but I know you're going to say, "But I see white on the side here." That's actually because of the preview of this mobile view.

If I close down the browser tools, you'll see it actually spans the full width. However, this math is not exact, so as a result, I can now scroll slightly to the left. And that is an unfortunate reality, because when you're using the vw property, the viewport width is calculated including the scrollbar on the right-hand side here. And right now, the scrollbar is hovering over the content, meaning my content is wider than what you see. This differs between browsers, and that's why we can't calculate for the scrollbar, so I'm going to cheat to fix this.

The way we cheat here is by grabbing the content area, so the entire area, and saying for the content area, I'm going to block the overflow-x, which is the horizontal overflow, and just set it to hidden. That way, the overflow that's happening because of this box is simply hidden and you can't see it. So now thanks to some CSS alchemy, we now have a meta content area that has a full-width background regardless of screen size.